# GPS Location Data Not Correct Display on Google Map

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i'm setting a new project in flutter with flutter_google_maps for tracking user location on map it's a basic project

But when i am moving devices or ride then my Location are point on map but not right place

Ex.

> I am walk on street road then google map navigation show exact my
>   location But my project not show exact location

Code are normal just use [Flutter Location Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

And Track Location Using this code

```
location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
  print(currentLocation.latitude);
  print(currentLocation.longitude);
});
```

And set to marker target value describe in [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

i google lot of things but no answer found who resolve my problem

Where I'm wrong ya any other methods use by other location tracking app

Thanks